# How to prevent Crashlytics bunching all exceptions from a Java library in a single issue

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, sentry

I'm using a Java library within an Android app which runs various (hamcrest) assertions which should log to Crashlytics on failure. Of course Crashlytics can't be included directly within the Java library so the library has to call some sort of defined factory logging method which itself in the app calls `Crashlytics.logException(ex)`. This works, and different logging schemes can be used in build and release types so a debug build crashes on a failed assertion whereas a failed assertion in production logs an exception to Crashlytics.

The problem is that the assertion failures all bunch into a single issue within Crashlytics, presumably because they all use a common factory method(s) of my own to circumvent the inaccessibility of the Crashlytics class within the Java library.

I think there's probably no solution to this bunching into a single issue (please no discussions of the benefits or not of running assertions in prod). Any ideas though?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard back from Fabric that there is no solution to this problem using Crashlytics.
UPDATE: I'm now using Sentry, which solves this; I can now log exceptions and other explanatory data just the same from the java component as from the Android app. I have no affiliation with Sentry and found the documentation poorer than Google's (although Google Crashlytics docs lacking imo). This meant it took longer than it might have to migrate, but now using it I find Sentry far superior to Crashlytics. There's a better user interface and much more flexibility than is available in the Fabric / Google product.
ACRA would be another way to go but I didn't want to have to start coding a server implementation for it.